# Generalization on $G$-sets: is there a name for a kind of group action where $a(bx) = (ba)x$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

An action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is a mapping $*:G\times X\rightarrow X$ such that

1. $e*x = x$ for all $x \in X$
2. $(ab)(x) = a(bx)$ for all $x \in X$ and all $a,b \in G$.

If one had a group and set that satisfied 1, but rather than satisfying 2 the following was satisfied instead:

$(ab)(x) = b(ax)$ for all $x \in X$ and all $a,b \in G$.

Consider an operation $*:SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\times \mathbb{F}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is the set of all quadratic forms whose matrices have integer entries. That is, $\mathbb{F}$ is the set of all $Q:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $Q({\bf v}) = {\bf v}^T\big[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{smallmatrix}\big]{\bf v}$, where $a, b, c$ are all integers.

Now let $Q$ have matrix $A$ and $M*Q({\bf v}) = Q(M{\bf v}) = (M{\bf v})^TA(Mv) = {\bf v}^T(M^TAM){\bf v} = Q'$. Then, $N*Q'({\bf v}) =  (N{\bf v})^T(M^TAM)(N{\bf v}) = {\bf v}^TN^T(M^TAM)N{\bf v} = {\bf v}^T(MN)^TA(MN{\bf v}) = (MN{\bf v})^TA(MN{\bf v}) = Q((MN){\bf v}) = (MN)*Q({\bf v})$

And so $N*Q'({\bf v}) = N*(M*Q({\bf v})) = (MN)*Q({\bf v})$

Would that be of interest? Is there any documentation on such a structure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've just described a [right group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Right_group_action)! In a right group action, members of a group act on the *right* of elements in $X$ (as the name suggests). A right group action has the following associativity rule: $$(xa)b = x(ab).$$ Notationally, it is different, but it's functionally the same as what you have. The important part is that the action of $ab$ is equivalent to the action of $a$, followed by the action of $b$.

The theory of right group actions, though, is equivalent to that of left group actions. If we have a right group action, we can transform it into a left group action by taking $$ ax = xa^{-1}, $$ which obeys the associativity rule because $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$. Thus, left and right group actions are, for the most part, equivalent.

---

Edited for the updated question: I might be missing something, but it looks like you could just use the notation of a right group action to describe this, so that $$ Q(\mathbf{v}) \ast M = Q(M\mathbf{v}). $$

Comment: Someone commented similarly before and deleted their comment, but I don't believe you are correct. I didn't mistype; the multiplication of ab is not commutative and I am asking because it seems my operation is not associative. Now that I realize that the associativity is the whole issue, I'm skeptical that I have anything to work with here, but a right action would be as you typed it and has to do with the direction of the multiplication. I intend left multiplication but with the reversal of ab in their procedural order. Perhaps I'll add the specific example; I should have to begin I suppose.

Comment: Sure, an example might help clarify things.

Comment: @MarcusShell can you elaborate on why you think octave's answer is incorrect? there is a natural bijection between the class of right $G$-actions and the class of objects you describe in your question:

Comment: given a map $f:G\times X\to X$ satisfying your axioms, the map $\overline{f}:X\times G\to X$ taking $(x,g)$ to $f(g,x)$ will be a right $G$-action on $X$. conversely, given a right $G$-action $f:X\times G\to X$, the map $\widetilde{f}:G\times X\to X$ taking $(g,x)$ to $f(x,g)$ will satisfy your axioms. the maps $f\mapsto\overline{f}$ and $f\mapsto\widetilde{f}$ are mutually inverse, so this give a precise sense in which the two notions are equivalent

Comment: I guess I was failing to see that the right action was reversing the procedural order. The concept of a G-set is rather new to me. Looking at it now, I believe @octave is correct. The concept of group actions is rather new to me. Would anyone have some good open source reading material that elaborates on the difference between a group action and a right group action? I was reading out of Fraleigh's "A First Course in Abstract Algebra," but it doesn't mention right action that I can see. Do they share all the same properties?

Comment: @MarcusShell They do share most properties, because we can create left actions out of right actions (briefly touched on in the answer) and vice versa. Right actions tend to come up when it's more convenient or more natural to write them that way, like in the example you've provided. I've also seen some people denote the action of the symmetric group as a right group action.

Comment: But the difference is largely just notation/convention. Because we can go between left and right group actions, they don't fundamentally represent different concepts. The reason left actions/the usual order of commutativity is more popular is mostly a matter of style.

Comment: Just curious–is this example from Fraleigh, or did you come up with/find it on your own?

Comment: This is something that's come up in my thesis research.